# Indentify Mail Id and URL

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am Creating a wp7 app, In his app m retrieving data by web service, in the data there is some urls and mail ids. but the look like simple text. how can i identify the urls and mail ids.?

Comment: In which format you are getting the response from web? XML or JSON or plain text?

Answer (score 1):

Use **regular expressions.**

For urls:

`Regex r = new Regex("(?\w+)://(?[\w@][\w.:@]+)/?[\w.?=%&=-@/$,]*");

// Match the regular expression pattern against a text string.

Match m = r.Match(text);

while (m.Success) 

{
     
//do things with your matching text 

     m = m.NextMatch();

}`

For emails you can use another regex:

`Regex regex = new Regex(@"^([\w.-]+)@([\w-]+)((.(\w){2,3})+)$");`